# Get old value before update a record in a form

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have 2 tables: Photos and Albums. In the album table I have a field with the number of photos of that album.

When I update a photo if I change the album I need to update the number of photos field of the albums table to reflect the changes.

```
    public function updateObject($values=null)
    {        
        $object = parent::updateObject($values);

        if($this->isNew)
        {
         ...
        }
        else
        {
          $old_album = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Photos')
                        ->find($object->getId())->getAlbums();
          if($old_album != $object->getAlbums()
             //update number of photos
        }
    }
```

but the `$object->getAlbums()` is always getting the same value as `$old_album;`
if I remove the `$old_album` the `$object->getAlbums()` gets the correct value.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `doUpdateObject()` method instead:

```
protected function doUpdateObject($values)
{
  // this is the album object before the update
  $oldAlbum = clone $this->getObject()->getAlbum();

  // refresh the object with the new values
  parent::doUpdateObject($values);

  // it's an update
  if (!$this->isNew())
  {
    // the old album is removed
    if (!$this->getObject()->get('album_id'))
    {
      // decrease the number of pictures in the old album and save it
      $oldAlbum
        ->setNumberOfPictures($oldAlbum->getNumberOfPictures() - 1)
        ->save();
    }
    elseif ($oldAlbum->get('id') != $this->getObject()->get('album_id'))
    {
      // decrease the number of pictures in the old album and save it
      $oldAlbum
        ->setNumberOfPictures($oldAlbum->getNumberOfPictures() - 1)
        ->save();

      // increase the number of pictures in the current album (save not required)
      $this
        ->getObject()
        ->setNumberOfPictures($this->getObject()->getNumberOfPictures() + 1);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // increase the number of pictures in the current album (save not required)
    $this
      ->getObject()
      ->setNumberOfPictures($this->getObject()->getNumberOfPictures() + 1);
  }
}
```

There is a lot of code duplication here and this is **not the best way to do it**, because you always have to do this for consistency when updated an album.

The whole logic should be moved into the model. **A better solution should be to use a `CountCache` behavior** like in [this](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/08-Advanced-Doctrine-Usage#chapter_08_writing_a_doctrine_behavior) example in the docs.